# The "comment edited" picture icon to be more subtle

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

[image: Giant pencil icon!!!]

The pencil icon for edited comments are far too large on P.SE + Meta. It seems like every other site uses the standard tiny pencil, which works well and is unobtrusive.

Comment: If I can add one remark: Badges icons. I think they would be more attractive if the round effect would be less... round... Having 1 or 2 pixels round and plain center will make them looks like real ones.

Comment: @Pierre I didn't notice before, but you're right, they look like spheres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the Edit icon. It is a subtle squiggle line now. I think it fits the whiteboard theme.

Comment: testing, one, two, three, four

Comment: testig too 1 2 3 4

Comment: it is kind of thick but I like it more than the pencil

Comment: When I tried a thinner line it blended in with text too much

Answer (score 7):

I agree, the pencil is massively overstyled (and far too literal) for a whiteboard design, and doesn't look correct. Perhaps an editing mark would be more appropriate -- like a small squiggle indicating "this was edited"

http://wadsworth.com/english_d/templates/student_resources/1413001890_burnett/UsageHandbook/edit_marks.htm

[image]
<sub>(source: [megp at www.westga.edu](http://www.westga.edu/%7Emegp/editing%20marks.gif))</sub>