# The "Flag comment" icon is too harsh

Tags: feature-request, design, comments

This is similar to [The "comment edited" picture icon to be more subtle](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/888), but it has to do with the "Flag" icon that shows up when hovering over comments.  On my machine it looks like this:

[image]

The blackness of the flag lines seem quite harsh when compared to the grays of the comment score and upvote triangle.

Could it be toned down to match the grays of the other things near it?