# "Flag" image inconsistancies

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is not a duplicate of [The "Flag comment" icon is too harsh](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/the-flag-comment-icon-is-too-harsh) because I actually like the image of the flag.

Rather, the problem is when you hover over it. On Meta, if you hover over the flag so it turns from white to black, the heights of the two images are not the same. It results in the control (and anything below it) being shifted up one pixel if the comment's length is short and does not increase the height.

For an example, see [Should our FAQ contain a list of what's off topic and if so what should that list contain?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/should-our-faq-contain-a-list-of-whats-off-topic-and-if-so-what-should-that-list) and hover over the flag of a short comment and the flag of a long comment.

It's different on Programmers. On Programmers, the height *and width* are off. See [Does tweeting 9 to 5 hurt job applicants?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23120/does-tweeting-9-to-5-hurt-job-applicants) for an example. (Specifically, GrandMasterB's comment on the original question post)

Due to the way browsers render font sizes and line lengths, this may vary.

However, there is an extremely simple way to know something is wrong: the bottom of the hovered "flag" image is cut off.

Comment: Here is a short comment (hover over the flag!) to demonstrate.

Comment: Here is a relatively long comment so you can see the different effects the incorrect image sizes have on the alignment of comments. I'm probably looking too deeply into this, as I imagine it's just a simple fluke with the CSS rules that splice the main sprite image, and that Jin can fix it in about 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm looking into this now. I can repro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was completed and deployed a while ago.